# How does a NIC that is aware of VLAN tagging work?

Tags: vlan, ethernet

I am trying to understand the purpose of a VLAN aware NIC on a server or work station?

I was under the impression a switch does most of the work when it comes to VLANs.

Is this another way of filtering traffic? Or does the NIC receive the traffic regardless?

Comment: It looks like if a switch has multiple VLANs, the ingress packets to the switch (egress from the endpoint), must be tagged. I assume this may be the purpose of the VLAN aware NIC.

Comment: Frames on access interface are not tagged, only frames on trunk interfaces are tagged, except for the native VLAN.

Comment: An example would be a big server with 5 virtual machines but only 1 nic (not a good idea, just an example). Maybe you want server1 to be VLAN 1 but server 2 to be VLAN 25. You can make the switch port a trunk and let the server tag the traffic. (the term tag is assuming 802.1q not ISL(old VLAN identification method))

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively you can answer your own question and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VLANs are fundamentally a technology to build multiple virtual Ethernet networks on one physical Ethernet network.

Sometimes you want to connect multiple VLANs to a host. Maybe the host is a router. Maybe it's a DHCP server. Maybe you want to have multiple logically separate networks that aren't routed to each other but a handful of hosts need a presence on more than one network.

Whatever the reason there are three approaches to doing this.

One is to just use a separate NIC and cable for each VLAN. This approach avoids the need for the host to have any concept of VLAN support but it means extra cables, extra switch ports and extra NICs. In some cases it may not even be practical.

A second approach is for the OS to implement a generic VLAN layer which handles the VLAN encapsulation and presents virtual interfaces. This can be done with virtually any NIC. Linux has had support for this for ages but afaict windows only added support recently.

A third approach is for the NIC vendor to implement VLAN support and creation of multiple virtual interfaces in the NIC driver presenting multiple virtual NICs to the OS. Many NIC vendors did this on Windows before MS added native support.

For some reason some NIC vendors seem to implement VLAN tagging in their drivers but not the creation of multiple virtual interfaces. This makes the VLAN tagging feature mostly pointless (outside of a few network troubleshooting scenarios).

Answer (score 1):

Some servers (and some workstations, but it is less common) are set up to be able to trunk with a switch. That means that the servers can be assigned addresses in multiple VLANs on the same link, and the servers can serve directly on the different networks.

In most cases, even with a VLAN capable NIC, servers and workstations are not configured for VLANs, and they will drop tagged frames, but it may be useful for a server to have connections to different VLANs in order to directly handle things like DHCP, NTP, etc. for the different VLANs without needing to be routed.

Comment: Thanks. Does the Ethernet driver need to support VLAN tagging, or is it done strictly in the NIC hardware?

Comment: Yes. You really end up with multiple virtual interfaces, but that is completely dependent on the host OS involved, which is off-topic here.